# opencv calcHist returns a black histogram after using cvtColor

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

I'm running an example in book "OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook", chapter 04. Only 2 histograms return by calcHist are black and the source is followed. And also the running result is shown below.

```
ColorHistogram() {

    // Prepare arguments for a color histogram
    histSize[0]= histSize[1]= histSize[2]= 256;
    hranges[0]= 0.0;    // BRG range
    hranges[1]= 255.0;
    ranges[0]= hranges; // all channels have the same range
    ranges[1]= hranges;
    ranges[2]= hranges;
    channels[0]= 0;     // the three channels
    channels[1]= 1;
    channels[2]= 2;
}

...

// Computes the 2D ab histogram.
// BGR source image is converted to Lab
cv::MatND getabHistogram(const cv::Mat &image) {

    cv::MatND hist;

    // Convert to Lab color space
    cv::Mat lab;
    cv::cvtColor(image,lab,CV_BGR2Lab);

    // Prepare arguments for a 2D color histogram
    hranges[0]= -128.0;
    hranges[1]= 127.0;
    channels[0]= 1; // the two channels used are ab
    channels[1]= 2;

    // Compute histogram
    cv::calcHist(&lab,
        1,          // histogram of 1 image only
        channels,   // the channel used
        cv::Mat(),  // no mask is used
        hist,       // the resulting histogram
        2,          // it is a 2D histogram
        histSize,   // number of bins
        ranges      // pixel value range
    );

    return hist;
}
```

Where is the bug? I cannot figure it out. Is the cvtColor(...) function running into error when converting an image into Lab format?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The code has errors. You are assigning random values to channels.
change ranges to hranges in calchist().
Try this:

```
cv::MatND getabHistogram(const cv::Mat &image) {

cv::MatND hist;

// Convert to Lab color space
cv::Mat lab;
cv::cvtColor(image,lab,CV_BGR2Lab);

// Prepare arguments for a 2D color histogram
hranges[0]= -128.0;
hranges[1]= 127.0;
channels[0]= 1; // the two channels used are ab
channels[1]= 2;

// Compute histogram
cv::calcHist(&lab,
    1,          // histogram of 1 image only
    channels,   // the channel used
    cv::Mat(),  // no mask is used
    hist,       // the resulting histogram
    2,          // it is a 2D histogram
    histSize,   // number of bins
    hranges      // pixel value range
);

return hist;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have inserted at the beginning the constructor code which has initialized the arrays.

Comment: But that's the initialization step. Your range changes after that and is not assigned again.

Comment: The 3 elements of ranges are assigned to the same array hranges, actually addresses. This time, the two elements of hranges are changed, which means changes in the first array ranges.

Comment: Can you please check once with this solution. And give the output?
I am not able to get it.
Thanks

Comment: Also I don't think addresses are being assigned.

Comment: Thanks for your response timely. The code is from a book's example, which is located here: https://github.com/vinjn/opencv-2-cookbook-src/blob/master/Chapter%2004/colorhistogram.h

Comment: Yes, I did check that. But What if there was an error there too.

Comment: I think there is some error in the code. And I'm new in opencv development, so I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I ran your code, and it returned the same black histograms.